# Want to add a validation using regular expression the format should be like this xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to put a validation using regular expression to get some value like this from text box xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x
Here is what I am trying

```
 [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CNIC")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(([0-9]{5})[-]([0-9]{7})[-][0-9]{1}\)$", ErrorMessage = "Entered CNIC format is not valid.")]
    public string Cnic { get; set; }
```

But it shows cnic format is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9+]{5}-[0-9+]{7}-[0-9]{1}$", ErrorMessage = "Entered CNIC format is not valid.")]
```